# How to check if there exists a non-negative element in an affine space?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Suppose that a $n$-dimensional affine space is defined with vectors $e_i=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0), i=1,\dots,n$ (the $1$ stands in the $i$-th place), i.e.
$$\mathcal{A}=\left\{\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\dots+\alpha_ne_n\mid\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k=1\right\}$$
and there is an affine subspace, e.g. $Ax+c$, in $\mathcal{A}$. The affine subspace is treated as a linear space $Ax$ shifted by vector $c$. In such case, linear space $Ax$ should be parallel to $\mathcal{A}$. The problem is that if there exist a non-negative element $x'$ in the affine subspace, i.e. $Ax'+c\ge0$. If not, it's desired to find out the closest point to achieve that goal.

The non-negativity requirement in the affine space $\mathcal{A}$ is equivelent to the definition of a standard $n$-dimensional simplex $$\Delta^n=\left\{\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\dots+\alpha_ne_n\mid\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k=1,\; \forall \alpha_k\ge0 \right\}$$
From the geometrical point of view, the problem is equivelent to check if a line or hyperplan, etc, intersects the simplex in the same affine space $\mathcal{A}$? if not, we want to find out the closest point to the simplex. [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm5Eq.jpg)

Is there some simple and efficient way to do so?

Comment: A quantifier is missing in $Ax+c \geq 0$. Do you want to check if there exists a non-negative element in an affine space? What is "a basis parallel to $\mathcal{A}$"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, i want to check if there exists a non-negative element in the affine subspace in $\mathcal{A}$. sorry for that incorrect  expressions. I treat the affine subspace as a linear space $Ax$ shifted by vector $c$. in such case, linear space should be parallel to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Please try and edit the question to make it clearer and specify these details directly in the text.

Comment: This problem is a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Could you give me some hints on how to define the objective and constraints?  Thank you in advance.